# critaria based on checking parameter in model

Tags: php, yii

cannot find solve of this small question. So I have tables

```
 project
 id | title | users
 1  | Main  | 1,3,8

 activity
 id | pid   | title
 1  | 1     | Add new project
```

in mi Activity model

```
public function getShow(){
    $users = $this->project->users;
    $userlist = explode(',', $users);
    if (in_array(Yii::app()->user->id, $userlist)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {return false;}
}
```

in SiteController i want to create CDbCriteria object to show activity timeline for authenticated user. But I dont how to check  "show" is true or false. for now my siteController`s action Index is

```
 $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
            $criteria->order = 'id DESC';
            $criteria->condition = 'here must check if show is true';

            $activity=new CActiveDataProvider('Activity',
                array(  'criteria'=>$criteria
                    )
            );
 $this->render('index',array(
    'activitys'=>$activity,
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Criteria will be applied to the database directly, you can't use a php function in it.
You shouldn't save your users in the table like that, you should make a link table

```
project_user
project_id | user_id
1          | 1
1          | 3
1          | 8
```

Generate a model for the table and setup relations correctly.
Then you can use

```
$criteria->with = array('project', 'project_user');
$criteria->condition = 'project_user.user_id = :user_id';
$criteria->params = array('user_id' => $user_id);
```

I think it would be even better to setup your relations so you can directly
access the activities from a user. Add this to the relations in your user model:

```
'projects' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Project', 'project_user(user_id, project_id)'),
'activities' => array(self::HAS_MANY 'Activity', 'pid', 'through'=>'projects', 'order'=>'activity.id DESC'),
```

Then in your controller you can do:

```
$user = User::model()->findByPk($user_id);
$activity = new CActiveDataProvider('Activity', array(
        'data'=>$user->activities,
)),
```